# How to skip bot from executing a command | discordpy

Tags: python, discord, command

I have a problem. I am building a bot to filter the chat, which has two important commands. "**addword**" for add a word to list
But here if I want to use the "**removeword**" command, the bot thinks it's a word in the list and deletes it and it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this might not be a perfect answer, but this might work or at least help:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if condition: # if this is true, the command will be executed
       await client.process_commands(message)
```

By doing that, we can set the variable `condition` to whatever you want to, for example:

`condition = not message.startswith('!removeword')`

The example makes it so that whenever the removeword command is being typed into the chat, it won't response or run the actual command.
Make sure to replace the prefix `!` with yours.